# How to restore SSH session after network failure on client PC

Tags: raspbian, ssh, putty

Sometimes my SSH session of my PC and Raspberry Pi is aborted, due to some network issues, eg. WIFI disconnected and connected back on PC. After that SSH client on PC (Putty) is saying that existing session is disconnected.

Question is:
Is there any possibility to restore the previously started session? I want to avoid of starting a new one.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot revive the `ssh` session once disconnected.  Sometimes if the network drops for a short enough time the session never disconnects, but once disconnected it is gone.  That's a security feature.

You can, however, keep your terminal session active between `ssh` sessions.  Check out the Linux programs `screen` or `tmux`.

Comment: I typically use "screen" to create a persistent and recoverable terminal.  While that's probably its most basic feature, it has many capabilities and is worth reading the docs (man screen) , etc. to learn about these capabilities.     Terminal must be under "screen" control or it wont be recoverable later (just type "screen" at the command prompt to put it under screen control).  To recover (after getting kicked off), re-login and type "screen -r".  I have not used tmux so I can't comment or compare (screen has been around for ages).

Comment: @TimCampbell: that's what I just wanted to ask regarding `screen`, but you have already answered. Only thing that I used `screen -r 'session_name'` instead of `screen -r`. It works the way I want, thanks!